# Android level17

Tags: android

I downloaded android4.2, using SDK Manager.
When I restart my eclipse, my sdk location is the same but don't work.
I am getting this error:

```
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.0.0 or above.  C...rsion is 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.  Please update ADT to the latest version.
```

I try to update my eclipse, but i am getting this error:

```
'Contacting Software Sites' has encountered a problem. No repository found at jar:file: /Downloads/JsonEditorPlugin-0.9.4/plugins/json.editor.plugin_0.9.4.jar!/.
```

Did anyone faced this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the ADT, otherwise it won't work. To do so select Help -> Check for Updates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update ADT to new version, to do so; Go to `Help` and click `install new software`

In there you have to click `work with:` drop-down and select your android ADT link.

Then eclipse will show the list of things to install, select them and click next. And you are done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Updating the ADT doesnt work for you , then simply try running Eclipse As Administrator! It worked for me. It is one of those bugs with eclipse that sometimes even go away after restarting it. Hope that helps.